# boto3 to read csv file in s3 with * asterisk

Tags: boto3

I have many csv files in s3 bucket and the full name is like:

```
fullname = “s3://mybucket/part-00000-46acaa37-75ba.csv”
```

I need  read  the files one by one so the filenames  will be using *

```
path = “s3://mybucket/*.csv”
```

The following code is working if I'm using  the fullname, but if using *, I will get the key wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
s3_client = session.client('s3')


bucket= “mybucket”
#key = part-00000-46acaa37-75ba.csv
s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

How could I work around this and read  all the files in the bucket?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should extend your code to:

1. Get all CSV files
2. Iterate list of files
3. Get each and load CSV as DataFrame

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
s3_client = session.client('s3')
bucket = "mybucket"

# Get all CSV files in the bucket
def get_csv_files(client, bucket):
    csv_files = []
    content = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket).get('Contents')
    for obj in content:
        key = obj.get('Key')
        if '.csv' in key:
            csv_files.append(key)
    return csv_files


for key in get_csv_files(s3_client, bucket):
    file_body = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key).get('Body')
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file_body.read()))
    # -> Do Something with DataFrame 'df'
```